# Is there a way to limit the number of minimized nb-windows in Nebular Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, nebular

I am working on an Angular Application, using Nebular NbWindowService. I have nb-windows that have minimize functionality. I want to be able to limit the number of minimized nb-windows to 3. How can I do that? So far, this is what I have done, but this logic of mine does not work:

```
openCODocument() {
        if (this.openWindowCount >= 3){

            const buttonsConfig: NbWindowControlButtonsConfig = {
                minimize: true,
                maximize: false,
                fullScreen: false,
            };
            this.windowsService.open(this.coachingFormComponent, {
                context: { coachingDocument: this.value }, buttons: buttonsConfig, title: this.windowTitle, windowClass: "window-form-popup", closeOnBackdropClick: false,
            });

        }

        this.openWindowCount++;
        
    }

    public closeWindow(){
        this.openWindowCount--;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can modify your logic by declare variable `minimizedWindowCount: number = 0;`:

```
openCODocument() {
  if (this.minimizedWindowCount >= 3) {
    return;
  }

  const buttonsConfig: NbWindowControlButtonsConfig = {
    minimize: true,
    maximize: false,
    fullScreen: false,
  };

  this.windowsService.open(this.coachingFormComponent, {
    context: { coachingDocument: this.value },
    buttons: buttonsConfig,
    title: this.windowTitle,
    windowClass: "window-form-popup",
    closeOnBackdropClick: false,
  });

  this.minimizedWindowCount++;
}
public closeWindow() {
  this.minimizedWindowCount--;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response, I have also tried this logic before, it dos not limit the number of minimized nb-windows, I can still minimize more than 3 nb-windows.